# Adding a Link to a Story Using the VersionOne SDK

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, versionone

I am writing code to create a story in VersionOne, but I can't figure out how to add a link to the story.

The code I currently use to create the story is:

```
        part = snapHash.Split(":")
        snapHash = part(0) & ":<" & part(1) & ">" & part(2) & " / " & part(3) & " \ " & errorMessage

        connector = V1Connector _
            .WithInstanceUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("InstanceUrl")) _
            .WithUserAgentHeader("VersionOne", "1.0") _
            .WithAccessToken(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AccessToken")) _
            .UseOAuthEndpoints() _
            .Build

        services = New Services(connector)

        projectId = services.GetOid("Scope:" & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Scope"))
        storyType = services.Meta.GetAssetType("Story")
        newStory = services.New(storyType, projectId)
        newAttribute = storyType.GetAttributeDefinition("Name")
        newStory.SetAttributeValue(newAttribute, snapHash)
        newAttribute = storyType.GetAttributeDefinition("Source")
        newStory.SetAttributeValue(newAttribute, "StorySource:" & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("StorySource"))
        newAttribute = storyType.GetAttributeDefinition("Description")
        newStory.SetAttributeValue(newAttribute, href)
        newAttribute = storyType.GetAttributeDefinition("Team")
        newStory.SetAttributeValue(newAttribute, "Team:" & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Team"))
        services.Save(newStory)
```

The href to VersionOne is being stored in the Description. I don't want to store the href in the Description, I want to add it as a link.

Comment: Consider adding what you already have (minimal solution) and be more concise with your question; is not very clear what the issue is.

Comment: I figured it out after a lot of trial and error. After the new Story is save, call AcceptChanges() on the Story object. This provides the Oid you need for the next step, which is to create a LInk Asset and pass it the Oid for the story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after a lot of trial and error. After the new Story is save, call AcceptChanges() on the Story object. This provides the Oid you need for the next step, which is to create a LInk Asset and pass it the Oid for the story.

```
connector = V1Connector _
    .WithInstanceUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("InstanceUrl")) _
    .WithUserAgentHeader("VersionOne", "1.0") _
    .WithAccessToken(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AccessToken")) _
    .UseOAuthEndpoints() _
    .Build

services = New Services(connector)

scopeOid = services.GetOid("Scope:" & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Scope"))
storyType = services.Meta.GetAssetType("Story")
storyAsset = services.New(storyType, scopeOid)
newAttribute = storyType.GetAttributeDefinition("Name")
storyAsset.SetAttributeValue(newAttribute, snapHash)
newAttribute = storyType.GetAttributeDefinition("Source")
storyAsset.SetAttributeValue(newAttribute, "StorySource:" & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("StorySource"))
newAttribute = storyType.GetAttributeDefinition("Description")
storyAsset.SetAttributeValue(newAttribute, errorMessage)
newAttribute = storyType.GetAttributeDefinition("Team")
storyAsset.SetAttributeValue(newAttribute, "Team:" & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Team"))
services.Save(storyAsset)
storyAsset.AcceptChanges()

linkType = services.Meta.GetAssetType("Link")
linkAsset = services.New(linkType, scopeOid)
newAttribute = linkType.GetAttributeDefinition("Asset")
linkAsset.SetAttributeValue(newAttribute, storyAsset.Oid)
newAttribute = linkType.GetAttributeDefinition("Name")
linkAsset.SetAttributeValue(newAttribute, "SnapDumps Link")
newAttribute = linkType.GetAttributeDefinition("OnMenu")
linkAsset.SetAttributeValue(newAttribute, True)
newAttribute = linkType.GetAttributeDefinition("URL")
linkAsset.SetAttributeValue(newAttribute, href)
services.Save(linkAsset)
```